# How to search with two different Solr cores?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have to perform a POC whereby content pages are shown in search along with products in the autosuggest.

I created a new facet search configuration(which created a new core for content page itemtype in Solr).

However the issue is while retrieving the data,as base site is not tied to this facet search configuration(as it is tied to facet search configuration for products out of the box).

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the new solr-index to your base site configuration

Comment: Thanks but this is a new configuration for the content pages.